# Mechanize: How to download a spreadsheet

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize by sparklemotion (https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize).

There is a site, called https://philjobs.org/. There, you can download a spreadsheet by clicking on a link.

I'm trying to automate the download of the spreadsheet. Here is what I have right now:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download

page = agent.get('https://philjobs.org')

agent.page.link_with(:text => 'Download spreadsheet').click.save
```

Instead of saving the spreadsheet, it saves the html. How can I save the spreadsheet instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download
url = "https://philjobs.org/jobQuery/execute?fromSavedquery=&email=&jobQuery.name=&format=csv&id=&view=On+screen+-+simple&typesToggler=Any+job+type&_jobTypes=&_jobTypes=&_jobTypes=&_jobTypes=&_jobTypes=&_jobTypes=&_jobTypes=&_jobTypes=&tenureTypesToggler=Any+contract+type&_tenureTypes=&_tenureTypes=&_tenureTypes=&_tenureTypes=&jobQuery.locationConstraint=NONE&jobQuery.institution.id=&jobQuery.institution.name=&jobQuery.institution.deleted=false&jobQuery.distance=50.0&jobQuery.city.id=&autonamejobQuerycity=&jobQuery.country=&jobQuery.region=&topicListToggler=Any+AOS&aocListToggler=Any+AOC&jobQuery.keywords=&moreOptions=&jobQuery.orderBy=Creation+time&searchFromDatePicker=&jobQuery.fromDate=date.struct&jobQuery.fromDate_day=&jobQuery.fromDate_month=&jobQuery.fromDate_year=&searchToDatePicker=&jobQuery.toDate=date.struct&jobQuery.toDate_day=&jobQuery.toDate_month=&jobQuery.toDate_year=&_withExpired="

agent.get(url).save('stackoverflow.csv')
```

When you click **Download spreadsheet** link, it submits the form using javascript as `get` method. The above `url` is is generated using all the input fields (params) of form.